# Java gridlayout with empty cells

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I want to show the status of some files in a Java GUI. Each file has a label and a button, the colour of the button represents the status of the file and clicking performs various operations. All this is working, the problem is that they are not showing correctly. I want it to appear as

```
[Label 1] [File 1] [File 2] [Label 2]
[Label 3] [File 3] [File 4] [Label 4]
etc.
```

To do this I have made a panel with a GridLayout

```
 new JPanel(new GridLayout((list.size() + 1) /2,4,3,3));
```

This works unless there is an odd number of files. Then the grid resizes itself, for example with 3 files I will get a 2x3 grid so label 2 shows on the next line. If I check for an odd number and then add 2 new JPanels after all the other controls it shows correctly but I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JavaDoc for [GridLayout.setColumns](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#setColumns%28int%29), it appears that not specifying the row count will cure your ills.

> Sets the number of columns in this layout to the specified value. **Setting the number of columns has no affect on the layout if the number of rows specified by a constructor or by the setRows method is non-zero.** In that case, the number of columns displayed in the layout is determined by the total number of components and the number of rows specified. *(my emphasis)*

Try this:

```
new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,4,3,3));
```

Answer (score -1):

> I was wondering if there is a better
>   way of doing this.

Yes, use [MiGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/).

Comment: Sorry, not really an option. Firstly the website is blocked by my work's firewalls and I don't have the permissions to install it anyway. It would have to be something in the standard java libraries.